# ggplot2 plot does not recognise class date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tried a lot of different date formats and had a look through forums, but nothing helped.

My code is quite simple. I am sucking simulation results from a database and then try to plot the samples with ggplot. Unfortunately the resulting plot does not show the right date time formatting on the x-axis. Here is my sample code:

```
df<-tryCatch(sqlQuery(myconn,sql),
     warning=function(w){print("FAIL! (warning)");return(NA)},
     error=function(e){print(paste("ERROR:",geterrmessage()));return(NA)})
```

The data frame df consists of two columns FIX_DATE with *posixct* format as well as SALDO which is in *num* format.

Now I've tried a lot of different date format conversions, as it was pointed out in different working groups, but nothing really worked. E.g.

```
dates<-as.Date(df$FIX_DATE)
```

or

```
library(lubridate)
dates<-ymd(df$FIX_DATE)
```

After date conversion:

```
samples <- data.frame(cbind(dates,df$SALDO))
colnames(samples) <-c("Dates","Values")
```

and the plot

```
 theme_set(theme_light())
ggplot(samples,aes(x=Dates, y=Values)) +
  geom_point(color = "navajowhite2",
             alpha = 0.5,
             shape = 1,
             stroke = 1) +
  #geom_smooth(color="red") +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "line", size = 1, colour="indianred2") +
  labs(title = "Monte-Carlo Szenarien", subtitle = "Darstellungsgitter in Jahren") +
  labs(y = "Nominal-Cashflows", x="Zeit") +
  theme(legend.position="none",
        plot.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "snow3"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "snow2"), 
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Szenarien Nominal-Cashflows", limits=c(1E+06, 3E+06)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

If I remove the line

```
scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I am getting the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4irnm.jpg). As you can see in the plot, the x axis only shows number of days, but not the right date format. If I add the line
   scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d")
I always get the error message:
*Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only*

Does anyone has a clue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give a sample of `df` ?

Comment: If you are not providing a fully reproducible example, then at least present your data in a manner that will enable us to at least begin to guess what might be going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue.

The library anytime did it!

```
library(anytime)
samples$Dates<-anydate(samples$Dates)
```

After that ggplot displays the right dates on the x-axis.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe `samples` seems to have only the 2 variables `Dates` and `Values`, but in the `aes` part you are referring to additional variables.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to split your work in pieces, so we can see where the actual problem is.

First: what does your input look like, exactly? I don't know what standard datetime MS SQL server format looks like, but most SQL-databases have different representations for dates and full date+time-objects, so I'm not sure which one you actually mean. Can you just post a sample of what `df$FIX_DATE` looks like?

Second: Does the conversion works as expected? What does your `dates`-object look like? If all values are `NA`, the conversion failed, or maybe some values failed, or something else failed. And is you final `data.frame` as you'd expect it?
Just looking at your error-message, I'd say `samples` does not contain a column Dates, but I wouldn't know why it wouldn't. So it's good to try and look if it is what you'd expect.

Third: Maybe there is a problem in plotting. I don't see anything directly wrong with your ggplot-call, but does it work if you trim it down? Like

```
ggplot(samples,aes(x=Dates, y=Values)) +
  geom_point()
```

If that succeeds, try bringing back other lines one by one, see where it fails.

Then, if you've tracked down where the problem is, it's quite probable you can solve the entire problem yourself. Or you can edit your question, then I can fully answer it.